# Same checking logic different exception message

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a web service accept two different interfaces(i.e. A and B) and there are some common fields which share same checking logic. However different error message have to be returned if the checking is failed and point out which field in the request body is invalid. Is there any way to reduce the code duplication for the checking logic.

```
Interface A may be accepting json as the request body,
{
  "companyAClient":{
      "id": 12345,
        "name": "ABC Limited",
        ...
    },
  ...
}

Interface B may be accepting xml as the request body with completly different structure compare to interface A
<MSG>
    ...
    <MSG.BODY>
        ...
        <COMPANY>
            <CLIENT>
                <ID>23456</ID>
                <NAME>XYZ Limited</NAME>
                ...
            </CLIENT>
            ...
        </COMPANY>
        ...
    </MSG.BODY>
</MSG>

private checkInterfaceA(String clientId, String clientName, other variables...) {
    Long id;
    try {
          id = Long.parse(clientId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InterfaceException("[EOS_E01] 'companyAClient.id' is empty.");
      }
      if(*clientId not exist in DB*) {
            throw new InterfaceException("[EOS_E02] 'companyAClient.id' not match with DB records.");
      }
        if(*clientName.toUpperCase() not found in DB*) {
                throw new InterfaceException("[EOS_E03] 'companyAClient.name' not match with DB records.");
        }
      Other checking...
}

private checkInterfaceB(String clientId, String clientName, other variables...) {
    Long id;
    try {
          id = Long.parse(clientId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InterfaceException("[E_XML_001] Parse Client ID error. Please check '/MSG/MSG.BODY/COMPANY/CLIENT/ID'.");
      }
      if(*clientId not exist in DB*) {
            throw new InterfaceException("[E_XML_002] Client ID not found error. Please check '/MSG/MSG.BODY/COMPANY/CLIENT/ID'");
      }
        if(*clientName.toUpperCase() not found in DB*) {
                throw new InterfaceException("[E_XML_003] Client name not found error. Please check '/MSG/MSG.BODY/COMPANY/CLIENT/NAME'");
        }
      Other checking...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a method where you pass the text in.

```
private checkInterface0(String clientId, String msgTemplate) {
  Long id;
    try {
        id = Long.parse(clientId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InterfaceException(msgTemplate);
    }
    if(*clientId not exist in DB*) {
        throw new InterfaceException(msgTemplate);
    }
  }
```

You might want to treat the template as either a filler (`throw new InterfaceException("Parse ID error in " + template);`) or by using string.format: `throw new InterfaceException(String.format(template, "Parse ID error")`. The parameter would be something like `"%s in interface A"`.

Comment: However the error messages for the two checking are different. Does it mean i have to pass msgTemplate for each checking?

Comment: Yes, of course.